# Comparing 3 cells to a 4th cell. 4th cell has random number of spaces between arguments

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

Sorry if this is lengthy but I want to be as clear as possible. Here is an example so that its easier to understand, then I will lay out the details, finally I will explain what I would like to do.

A picture of my example is at: imgur.com/9uK9So9

I couldn't post a picture because of <10 rep :/

Column A- the "name" portion of it must be exactly 12 characters and the "number" portion must be 5 (not including the '.').
So, cell A1 is "ADAM2_______25.000". 
name="ADAM2_______"
number="25.000"

Column B-just the name portion without any extra spaces.
So, cell B2 is "ADAM2"

Column C-same as column B but may be different (the reason I'm doing the comparison)

Column D-the number portion without the trailing 0's.
So, cell D2 is "25"

Column E is where I want the comparison to output something along the lines of true or false.

I know that columns C and D are correct, I am not sure if A and B are though. I want to compare column A with the values in Column C and D but I do not know how to account for the random number of spaces in between the name and number portion in Column A. Also I want to make sure Column B matches column C but that should be pretty easy once the first part is done.

Basically, how to I account for the varying number of spaces/trailing 0s in my comparison?

Mostly I've been using Conditional IF/AND statements. I tried using the CONCATENATE function but it didn't seem to work as I was hoping.

Thanks!

^^EDIT 1

In column E I tried =IF(A2 = (B2+D2),TRUE(),FALSE()) But obviously that will not work. It gives an #VALUE! error.

I tried splitting Column A into 2 more columns using text to columns. This got rid of the trailing 0s and the extra space(s) after the end of the "name" part. From here I think It should be pretty easy with just basic IF statements.

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the string-searching functions - either FIND [case sensitive] or SEARCH [not case sensitive]. These functions look at a given string, and check to see whether a search term is within that string. If it is present, it gives you the character number where the match starts; if it is not present, it gives an error.

So to see if A2 contains the term in B2 as well as the term in D2, you would use:

```
=if(and(isnumber(search(B2,A2)),isnumber(search(D2,A2))),"BOTH TERMS PRESENT", "AT LEAST 1 TERM NOT PRESENT")
```

Note that this doesn't compare with column C at all - I can't tell whether you actually are trying to compare that one are not.